# Vim is not detecting commands when typed slowly

Tags: vim

I recently installed a plugin called [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) by [Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope) on vim (gVim) installed on Windows. I use [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) for managing plugins. In case it matters, I have also installed [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to swap **Esc** and **Caps Lock** by means of a simple script, which **AutoHotKey** understands. Before installing the mentioned plugin, commands could be typed at a slow speed and vim (gVim) would recognized them. For example, if you typed **[p** with a slight pause between **[** and **p**, vim would still recognize the command. But now, after installing the plugin, when I use the commands ( for example **[b** ) mentioned in the documentation (helpfile) of the plugin, the commands are not recognized when they are typed slow with pauses between the keys. However, they work fine, when typed at a quick speed. Also, native commands are still working fine. Is the plugin built that way, or is something wrong elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the following value:

```
:verbose set timeoutlen?
```

That's the time (in milliseconds) that you have between typing each key of a mapping (with a default of 1 second).

If you're only now experiencing these problems, that may be because:

- a plugin has decreased the value (the `:verbose` should tell you)
- you only now use plugins that have "longer" mappings; beforehand you just didn't notice

In any case, if you're "suffering" under this, just increase the value in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @Karkat Thanks buddy. Does **timeoutlen** apply only to **external** plugins commands? Actually this is my first **feature** plugin (I was already using a color scheme plugin). I did not see such an issue with native commands before. Anyways, now I have increased the value to 10 seconds. I think this should be sufficient.

Comment: It's only for _mappings_, not for multi-key builtin commands, right.